# How to improve the structure of URLs

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, seo, google-search-console

From the [article](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=76329) at google's webmaster center and SEO's pdf, I think I should improve my website's URLs structure.

Now the news url looks like "***news.php?id=127591***". I need to rewrite it to something like "***/news/127591/this-is-article-subject***"

The problem is if I change the structure of url to the new one. Can I still keep the old one working? If both url working, how to avoid search engine like google and bing to search twice times for one article?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTTP 301** permanent redirect from the old URL to the new URL

an HTTP 301 redirect has the property of communicate a new (permanent) URL for an old (outdated) ressource to google (and other clients). google will transfer most/all of the allocated value from the old URL to the new URL.

Answer (score 1):

Also, in order to improve the arquitecture of your website, you must keep a clean structure by inserting links within all its pages/posts. But be careful, you must not do this lightly, or Google´s robot will get confused and leave.
Structure is key to your SEO
1. Find one page which is the "really important page" for any given keyword
2. direct relevant content from other pages which is relevant to that particular kw
3. repeat with every relevan kw

I´m gonna leave this post for you, where I explain this more in depth, hoping that you understand spanish. http://coach2coach.es/la-estructura-web-es-la-base-del-posicionamiento/

Answer (score 0):

Yep.. you can use robots.txt to exclude news.php, and create an xml sitemap with the new URLs. mod_rewrite can be set to only change directories, with trailing slashes.. so all files in your root directory should work fine.